# Xcode editor default to -(void) instead of -(voidPtr)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In Xcode (3.2 on Snow Leopard) when I start to type out a function such as

```
-(void)myFunctionName {

}
```

When I first start typing the code hint is

```
-(voidPtr
```

1. What is the difference between `void` and `voidPtr`? I assume that `voidPtr` is a pointer of some kind, what cases call for its use? Do I want to be using `voidPtr` instead of `void`?
2. Can I change a preference in the editor that will default to `void` and then I can type P and tab complete to `voidPtr` if I want?
3. Is there a general way to configure or prioritize code hints so that common hints show up before more obscure code hints?
4. Can I create code hint shortcuts? Where I type a couple of characters and a command to expand common boilerplate code?
5. What are some recommended practice tutorials for getting really productive in Xcode editing?

**Update:** Based on Darren's suggestion it looks like voidPtr comes from

```
CarbonCore/Threads.h

...

/*
    The following ProcPtrs cannot be interchanged with UniversalProcPtrs because
    of differences between 680x0 and PowerPC runtime architectures with regard to
    the implementation of the Thread Manager.
 */
typedef void *                          voidPtr;
```

I am running Xcode on a fresh vanilla install of Snow Leopard. And I have not done anything exotic with my projects. Just starting some very basic tutorials on Xcode and Objective C. Any experienced Objective C folks have useful background info here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** This **was** a bug in older versions of Xcode. Bug #7256749 has been fixed. I just tried with the newest version of Xcode, and everything is roses.

**Historical Info:** (for Xcode versions prior to the release of Xcode 4.0)

If you start typing a C-style function declaration:

```
void SomeFunc(...
```

Then "void" will appear as the first suggestion. Xcode's code sense applies different rules depending on the surrounding syntax, and when you are creating an Objective-C function declaration, it appears to exclude all of the built in types, including `void`.

I have filed a bug with Apple (via [bugreport.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com)), and I recommend that you do the same. Apple prioritizes their software fixes (at least partially) based on the number of duplicate reports that they see for a given problem.

**Note:** Here is the full text of the bug report submitted to Apple:

> Summary:
>   Xcode's code sense provides a list of suggested matches as you type. This list is filtered depending on context. When typing an Objective-C method declaration, the built-in types (void, int, float, etc.) are  filtered out. Numeric types such as int and float may be intentionally missing in order to encourage the use of NSInteger or NSNumber, but the void type is still used all the time, and should really appear in the list of suggestions.
>
> Steps to Reproduce:
>   1. Open Xcode
>   2. Create a new project with the Cocoa Application template
>   3. Open the application delegate header file
>   4. Begin creating a method declaration with a void return type:
>       - (vo
>   5. Press escape to bring up the complete list of suggested completions
>
> Expected Results:
>   I would expect to see "void" at the top level of the suggestion list, and I would expect it to be highlighted as the most likely choice.
>
> Actual Results:
>   The list does not even contain "void", and the selected candidate is "voidPtr", which is declared in CarbonCore/Threads.h
>
> Regression:
>   Unknown, but it definitely happens in the latest build of Xcode (3.2 (1610)) on Mac OS X10.6
>
> Notes:
>   See discussion on StackOverflow.com ([Xcode editor default to -(void) instead of -(voidPtr)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484154/xcode-editor-default-to-void-instead-of-voidptr/))

Comment: Thank you for your response. Filed a bug report as well.

Is there a way to customize the filter options in Xcode?

Comment: Not that I know of. I've found a few of the defaults frustrating at times, but overall it still works. If you find a way to customize them, be sure to let us know!

Comment: Apple has fixed this with Xcode version 4.0. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

voidPtr isn't a standard Objective-C or Cocoa type.  XCode is likely presenting `voidPtr` because it found that symbol somewhere in your project.

You can select "File > Open Quickly" (⌘⇧D) from the menu and type `voidPtr` to see where that symbol is defined.  You can also do the same by holding down the Command key and double-clicking a symbol in your source code.